# force showModalDialog use post method

Tags: javascript, html, http

Is it possible to force “showModalDialog” to use “post” method?
I can see that in many cases it use “Get” method.

Can it be configured at the client or server side?
(I am using Internet Explorer / WebSphere 7.0)

Just to clarify, I am trying to get a popup html page from the server. Sometimes it use “GET” and sometimes it use “POST”

Comment: Huh? Use post when doing what? Getting the HTML to show? Submit a form in an iframe I would think

Answer (score 0):

In your modal dialog, put a `form` with `method="POST"` and a submit button.
When the user click the submit it will use `post`.

If you want to use ajax, just define it in the ajax call:

**Pure javascript**

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","demo_post.asp",true);
```

**Jquery**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
 ...
```